# Lithium: load view from library

Tags: templates, plugins, view, lithium

I am working on a 3rd party library in `PROJECTROOT/libraries/mylib`. have a controller in `mylib/controllers`, which is working. li3 tells me it expects a view in `PROJECTROOT/app/views/` -- how can I load a view from `mylib/views` instead of `app` ?

Answer (score 1):

That can be easily achieved by setting the render paths in a controller. You probably want to do that for every controller in mylib, so a BaseController that all controllers extent from is a good idea. You can then use lithiums default called method _init() to setup the configurtion like that:

```
class BaseController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function _init() {
        parent::_init();

        $this->_render['paths'] = array(
            'template' => array(
                LITHIUM_APP_PATH . '/views/{:controller}/{:template}.{:type}.php',
                '{:library}/views/{:controller}/{:template}.{:type}.php',
            ),
            'layout' => array(
                LITHIUM_APP_PATH . '/views/layouts/{:layout}.{:type}.php',
                '{:library}/views/layouts/{:layout}.{:type}.php',
            ),
            'element' => array(
                LITHIUM_APP_PATH . '/views/elements/{:template}.{:type}.php',
                '{:library}/views/elements/{:template}.{:type}.php',
            ),
        );
    }
```

You can have a look at it here: https://github.com/bruensicke/radium/blob/master/controllers/BaseController.php

Please note, that i set it up that way, so the application can overwrite specific views in order to customize it further.

Also, there is an issue/pull-request on github regarding that topic, have a look here:

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/pull/650

Comment: Just noticed that you are the author of the pull-request - so you probably have that solved. But in case you need it before the pull-request is accepted, you can use above code.